# Execute a stored procedure asynchronously in a Rails application

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sidekiq

I have an application in Rails and what I'm trying to do is execute a database stored procedure asynchronously when a user navigates from one particular page to another - the user must continue his navigation while the stored procedure runs.

I don't really need to have a callback when the procedure finishes, I just need to run it in background.

I'm trying to use the following code:

```
require 'eventmachine'
require 'em-http'
require 'fiber'

def async_fetch(url)
  f = Fiber.current
  http = EventMachine::HttpRequest.new(url).get :timeout => 10
  http.callback { f.resume(http) }
  http.errback { f.resume(http) }

  return Fiber.yield
end

EventMachine.run do
  Fiber.new{
    url = url_for :controller => 'common', :action => 'execute_stored_procedure'
    data = async_fetch(url)
    EventMachine.stop
  }.resume
end
```

The problem here is that when the stored procedure starts, the user must be redirected to another page, but the next page remains "pending" and renders only when the procedure finishes.

I tried to use *thin* (in my development environment) as my server with --threaded option with no success, and now I'm thinking about using Phusion Passenger Enterprise in multithreaded mode in the production server, but it's a commercial version and it does not have any trials, I'm afraid that it's not what I need.

Does anybody know a good solution to achieve this? To execute the stored procedure I have to make a request to the same webserver my application is running, so my webserver must accept multiple connections at a time (multithreaded), is it correct?

Some useful information:

- Ruby 1.9.3p385
- Rails 3.2.13
- SQL Server 2012

Development:

- Linux lucid32 2.6.32-45-generic #102-Ubuntu (vagrant machine)
- thin webserver

Production:

- Linux debian 2.6.32-5-xen-amd64
- Apache / Phusion Passenger

I really appreciate any help.

**UPDATE #1**

I tried celluloid as recommended by Jesse.
Here is my code:

```
require 'celluloid/autostart'
class PropertyWorker
  include Celluloid

  def engage(args)
    ActiveRecord::Base.execute_procedure("gaiainc.sp_ins_property_profiles", args[:id])
  end
end

...

def create
    @property = Property.new(params[:property])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @property.save
        PropertyWorker.new.async.engage({:id => @property.id})
        format.html { redirect_to new_enterprise_property_activation_url(@property.enterprise.id, @property.id) }
        format.json { render json: @property, status: :created, location: @property }
      else
        format.html { render action: "new" }
        format.json { render json: @property.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
end
```

When then action 'create' is called, the record is created, the stored procedure starts but the next page is not rendered, the request remains "pending" in the browser until the procedure finishes. As soon as the procedure finishes, the page is rendered.

I can't figure out what is going on. Was the procedure not supposed to run in background?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In something like this, I recommend either [Sidekiq](http://sidekiq.org/) or [Celluloid](http://celluloid.io/). What you want to do is spin off a thread and execute something, returning access to the calling process and having it continue on.

Sidekiq would require a separate process to run (and Redis), Celluloid would not. Otherwise, they are similar.

**Sidekiq:**

```
class AsyncProc
  include Sidekiq::Worker

  def perform(args)
    CodeToExecuteStoredProcedure.engage! args
  end
end
```

You'd call it with:

```
AsyncProc.perform_async {whatever: arguments, you: want}
```

This would schedule a job in Redis and get executed when a spare Sidekiq worker has time

**Celluloid:**

```
require 'celluloid/autostart'
class AsyncProc
  include Celluloid

  def engage(args)
    CodeToExecuteStoredProcedure.engage! args
  end
end
```

And to call it:

```
AsyncProc.new.async.engage {whatever: arguments, you: want}
```

This would execute asynchronously, pretty much right away.

Comment: +1 for Celluloid in this case. Managing events, fibers and threads can be a difficult task, and it makes a lot of sense to utilize one of the pre-baked frameworks to do it.

Comment: I created a small rails app that uses celluloid. It returns control to the browser immediately. https://gist.github.com/jwo/5629696 ... Would you change your PropertyWorker to simply sleep when `engage!`? I think  it's possible the stored procedure is locking your database.

Comment: Jesse, I tried to make a simple "sleep" instead of executing the procedure and it worked! I will take a look now if the procedure is locking the database and will post the results. Thank you!

Comment: My stored procedure is now making a simple select with 'nolock' parameter just to make sure that it's not locking the database. My request is still with a pending status until the procedure finishes. I'll try to deploy the application to my production server to check the behavior.

Comment: Jesse, the stored procedure is not locking the database, I created a procedure with a simple select, with a simple sleep, with a big while loop, and others that don't lock the database but the behavior is always the same (tried in development environment using thin server and in production using phusion passenger. When I put a simple sleep in my method it works, but when I call a stored procedure with _ActiveRecord::Base.execute_procedure_ I have to wait until it finishes otherwise my page request remains pending. I just don't know what's going on. Any idea?

Comment: I think the problem is that _ActiveRecord::Base.connection_ is the same, so when I call _ActiveRecord::Base.execute_procedure_ it opens and gets the connection and my application have to wait until the stored procedure finishes (and consequently closes the connection) to access the database. Is it possible?

Comment: It's possible. Try changing over to sidekiq -- it'll be goodness.

Comment: It worked like a charm with _sidekiq_. Thank you very much for your help, Jesse!

Answer (score 1):

If you want to run something asynchronous from the request/response thread, which is what this sounds like, then you should be using a background processing system to do this.

There are various gems that do this - look into [DelayedJob](https://github.com/tobi/delayed_job), [Resque](https://github.com/resque/resque), and [Sidekiq](https://github.com/mperham/sidekiq) as some of the more popular options.  They will typically require some backing store (Redis, MongoDB, your Rails database) to keep track of tasks that need to be, or are currently, running.

Alternatively, Unicorn might work for you as it actually spawns separate processes that won't lock the GVL - but I don't think the underlying system should be determined by the kind of concern you are addressing.

Comment: I tried _celluloid_ (check my last update to the post and comments in Jesse's answer) with no success. I'll try to use _Unicorn_ as you said to check the behavior. Thank you.

Comment: Same behavior with _Unicorn_ - it's probably something with the database

Comment: I just got it to work with _sidekiq_, like you said at first. Thank you very much for your help.